# What's an example of a function where both Left & Right hand limits are finite, but not equal?

Tags: calculus

Can someone help me find a function where both the LHL & RHL are finite numbers (such as 1, 2, 3....etc), but not equal to each other?

For example, consider f(x) = |x| - x. When x -> 0, we know that LHL = 0 and RHL is also equal to 0.

Is there a function where these are unequal?

EDIT: Note when I say function, I do not mean just graph. I mean it formulated as f(x) = something

Comment: Where are you stuck? Could you draw an example? What would it look like?

Comment: What does the derivative of |x| look like?

Comment: As a hint, a formula like $f(x) = |x| - x$ is not necessary to define a function. The previous comment suggesting that you **draw** an example is an even better hint.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think you folks are missing the point. The example that I have shared is an example of what my function shouldn't look like. I just want to know of a function where the LHL & RHL exist.

Comment: But thanks @DavidK - drawing such a function is a nice way of giving an example of such a situation. But I really do need a function defined as y = f(x), so that I can teach my students that such situations exist too.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing "function" with "formula". Not all functions can be expressed symbolically. But the floor function $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$ is an example.

Comment: Got it, please note the edit to the question

Comment: You're going to struggle a bit if you're trying to build a function from components that are continuous through addition, multiplication or composition because those typically preserve continuity. You're going to have to use a function that's already defined as discontinuous - like the suggested floor function, or a Heaviside step function or signum function.

Comment: Okay got it. You're right, I was struggling trying to put this together using components that are continuous in themselves. Thank you so much @ConMan - for the clarification and the helpful explanation!

Comment: I figured eventually we needed to get to a formal definition, not just a picture. Have your students seen piecewise functions before? What about the greatest integer function?

Comment: Thanks @Karl for describing my question in better terms, and thanks for the example!

Comment: No they haven't actually. But this would probably be a good time to introduce the GIF!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the helpful comments, let me answer the question myself and close this thread.

So for a function to have both sided limits defined, but them not being equal to each other will result in a discontinuity at that point.

The floor function or the greatest integer (less-than or equal to) function are good examples of such a function.

[image: Floor Function]

Picture Source: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html

Consider the above function f(x) = ⌊⌋

When x approaches 0 from the left:

$\lim_{x \to -0} f(x)$ = -1

But when x approaches 0 from the right:

$\lim_{x \to +0} f(x)$ = 0

In this case, both LHL and RHL are finite numbers , but $LHL \ne RHL$

Comment: It's been several decades, but this may very well be the first function I saw in school that had distinct RH and LH limits.